# What does credentials.JSON do when working with Google API?

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I'm fairly new to programming, I've just got the basics down in terms of object oriented programming and a little bit of databases. I was just wondering if anyone could give an in-depth explanation as to what Google's credentials.JSON file does when trying to use their API. I'm using visual studios and c# if that's important.

Answer (score 1):

Google's credentials.JSON contains information about your application that will identify it to google.  It also gives your application some information it needs in order to find Googles oauth server and use it.

You should be aware that there are three types of files.  Web, native and service account.  The files are designed for use with different types of applications.

A web application would use web credentials and the code designed for authorization with a web application
A native application would use native credentials and code designed for use with authorization of a native application.
An application which would be just for server to server communication between data the developer owns and does not need to access user information would use service account credentials and the code needed for authorization with a service account.

Below is the example of the oauth credentials used for a web application.

```json
{
   "web":{
      "client_id":"450547033183-5uok2fl5u.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "project_id":"developer-info-2b41cd",
      "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_secret":"Fu8ZmTGOMvHjqQEseZE68hg",
      "redirect_uris":[
         "https://developer-info-2b41cd.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler"
      ],
      "javascript_origins":[
         "http://localhost",
         "http://localhost:5000",
         "https://developer-info-2b41c.firebaseapp.com"
      ]
   }
}
```

- client_id Identifies the client to google so they know which oauth client this is you can create more then one set of credentials per project.
- project_id your project on Google developer console.
- auth_uri The Url endpoint you will need to contact google to authorize
- token_uri  The uri end point you will need to request the initial token.
- auth_provider_x509_cert_url The location of all the oauth certificates
- client_secret think of this as the password for your client id.
- redirect_uris Authorized urls where you would like the authentication to be returned to.

99% of this is used by Googles Oauth2 server to authorize both your application and the user attempting to login.  If your interested in how Oauth2 works i suggest reading though some of the RFC's for Oauth.